# Xen PV Linux machines always remain "b". Never change to "r"

Tags: xen

I'm curious if this is the expected state for virtual machines under Xen. I've set up two machines and their states remain `-b----` and never seem to move to `r----` which Domain-0 is at.

```
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  5788     6     r-----   5870.5
kirk                                         3  1024     1     -b----     20.2
picard                                       2  1024     1     -b----   1987.8
```

If I console to either, I can log in. If I ssh to either it also works. From what I can tell these two machines are functioning fine, just can't seem to figure out why they're not "ready".

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It usually means:

1. The domain is waiting for I/O or.
2. There is nothing for the domain to do.

Considering that you just setup the domains and it doesn't appear that you have done anything with them yet, 2) appears to be the most likely answer.

As for Domain-0, that is operating system console and that will always be in the state of "r" because it is managing everything, including the DomUs kirk and picard.